# $.getJSON not working.. at all

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to feed a PHP array over to jQuery using JSON but am not having much luck.

```
$(".add-size").click(function(event) {

    $("#is_ajax").val('true');

    var dataString = 'ID=' + $("#product_ID").val() + '&size=' + $(this).val() + '&is_ajax=' + $("#is_ajax").val();

    $.getJSON( "../bin/func/actions/add.action.php", dataString, function(data) {
        $("#runningQuantity").text(data.runningQuantity);
        $("#runningTotal").text(data.runningTotal);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

is the jQuery that's not working well.

```
$list['runningTotal'] = $runningTotal;
$list['runningQuantity'] = $runningQuantity;

echo json_encode( $list );
```

is the relevant PHP in add.action.php and the string this creates seems to be formatted OK. eg:

```
{"runningTotal":90,"runningQuantity":18}
```

But nothing happens in either #runningTotal or #runningQuantity, they just stay the same? I may be totally missing the point here.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code, and perhaps a fully-working example using http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: first of all move event.preventDefault(); to the top of the click-event. Not sure if it's needed, but it's been explained so on the jquery site. Also this `$("#is_ajax").val()` seems like a useless parameter in the data as you're setting it to true yourself?

Comment: Ensure that your success handler is getting hit and that the data it's recieving is what you expect using either `console.log` or `alert`...

Comment: Try binding to [`.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and see if anything returns. getJSON will just suppress if anything bad happens.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eyRGk/ - if that helps... the #is_ajax thing is for the PHP to know if the request has come via JS and if not then to process differently, it's not relevant to this problem.

Comment: alert( data.runningQuantity ); inside the success handler says it's undefined but if i go direct to the PHP page then the string it produces (above) seems fine..

Answer (score 0):

Per Jquery's [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson) the data to be sent to server has to be in key value pairs. You can do one of two things:

```
$.getJSON( "../bin/func/actions/add.action.php", {Id : $("#product_ID").val(), .....}, function(data) {
        $("#runningQuantity").text(data.runningQuantity);
        $("#runningTotal").text(data.runningTotal);
    });
```

or 
add the datastring to the URL by adding a ? so that it becomes a querystring.

```
$.getJSON( "../bin/func/actions/add.action.php?" + datastring, function(data) {
            $("#runningQuantity").text(data.runningQuantity);
            $("#runningTotal").text(data.runningTotal);
        });
```

HTH

Comment: This will teach me to post the full code in future - I was checking $_POST['is_ajax'] in the PHP script but this JSON method is done through GET as I've just discovered. I bet if I'd posted that bit we'd have solved this in minutes! Apologies for wasting folks' time and thanks.